# Complex numbers - solve equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem, it would help me.

The task is: Solve the equation where they are $z\in \mathbb{C},m\in \mathbb{N}, n\in \mathbb{N}$

$z^n=z^{-m}$

I tried this:

$z^n=z^{-m}\\z^n=\frac{1}{z^m}\\z^mz^n=1\\z^{m+n}=1\Rightarrow k=m+n\\\cos(\frac{2(m+n)\pi}{n})+i\sin(\frac{2(m+n)\pi}{n})$

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step is wrong. There are $m+n$ values for $z$ given by $z=e^{\frac {2 \pi i k} {m+n}}$, $ 0\leq k <m+n$.

Comment: In trigonometric form: $\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{m+n})+i\sin(\frac{2k\pi}{m+n})$ ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you !! :-)

Comment: @SrdjanPesevic don't forget you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark

Comment: Okey, thanks ! :-)